# не отрабатывает Handler.postAtTime

Tags: android, android-handler

Есть задача в начале каждого часа запускать задание в службе.
Для этого там настроен Handler. Но Runnable запускается только один раз.
`Handler.postAtTime` почему-то не отрабатывает, может я не правильно понимаю значения аргумента?

```
private void startTimer() {
    mTime = date.getTime();
     mHandler.removeCallbacks(timeUpdaterRunnable);
     mHandler.post(timeUpdaterRunnable);
}
private Runnable timeUpdaterRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long step=60*60*1000;
        long nextTime=(mTime-mTime%step)+step;
        mHandler.postAtTime(this, nextTime);
       .............

    }
};
```

Comment: А на каком Андроиде тестите? Может просто не дожидаетесь? Аргумент uptimeMillis означает только время в проснувшемся состоянии. Время спячки девайса не засчитывается.

Comment: Api22 на эмуляторе. оставлял на несколько часов. uptimeMillis  это не абсолютное время в мили секундах?

Comment: Может лучше AlarmManager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы здесь что-то не так вычисляете.

```
long nextTime=(mTime-mTime%step)+step;
```

У вас каждый раз будет вычисляться одно и то же значение, mTime же не меняется?

Используйте может

```
boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)
```

Проще будет, все равно система вам не гарантирует точного времени старта.

Comment: спасибо за замечание в вычислениях, нужно менять. Видимо прийдется использовать postDelayed  с коректировкой. За сутки там набегает большая погрешность, вот и хотел попробовать другой метод